# How to play default Windows OS (not only) "finish/completed" sound using Java?

Tags: java, audio

How to play default Windows OS (not only) "finish/completed" sound using Java? Or should I use some prepared sound file? Maybe I should get sound file location from some registry value?

I found these possibilities for Windows OS:

```
String propnames[] = (String[]) Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getDesktopProperty("win.propNames");
System.out.println("Supported windows property names:");
for (int i = 0; i < propnames.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(propnames[i]);
}
```

Output:

```
(...)
    win.sound.asterisk
    win.sound.close
    win.sound.default
    win.sound.exclamation
    win.sound.exit
    win.sound.hand
    win.sound.maximize
    win.sound.menuCommand
    win.sound.menuPopup
    win.sound.minimize
    win.sound.open
    win.sound.question
    win.sound.restoreDown
    win.sound.restoreUp
    win.sound.start
(...)
```

And later for example:

```
Runnable runnable = (Runnable) Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getDesktopProperty("win.sound.exclamation");
if (runnable != null) runnable.run();
```

How about other systems?

Also as an alternative, it could be:

```
try {
    try (Synthesizer synthesizer = MidiSystem.getSynthesizer()) {
        synthesizer.open();

        MidiChannel[] channels = synthesizer.getChannels();

        channels[0].noteOn(60, 60);
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        channels[0].noteOff(60);
    }
} catch (InterruptedException | MidiUnavailableException ex) {
     Logger.getLogger(TestIt.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

But here I have to create my own band and release greatest single of all the times :)

Comment: Java is OS independent, so if you want a particular sound to be played of Windows it's most likely not in the standard Java library. So indeed you should include some audio files in you project yourself. 

Though I think it's bad practice to use Windows sounds on Mac OSX/Linux systems. Will your application only be used on Windows?

Comment: No, it is cross platform. I suspect I must include my own sound file..

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you are on the right track, you can play a system sound with this:

```
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getDesktopProperty("win.sound.exclamation");
```

Or for the beep (works in Mac OS too):

```
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
```

Comment: Are there any similar properties in Mac OS too?

Comment: Unfortunately these are there only in Windows. The system sounds on Mac OS are located in /System/Library/Sounds/ as aiff files. According to the Java Desktop application guide from Apple, you can play sound with Apple Core Audio Framework: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Java/Conceptual/Java14Development/04-JavaUIToolkits/JavaUIToolkits.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001901-SW1.

Comment: Yes, it led me to Java `Synthesizer` class, thanks. Maybe its even better solution :)